# Can I use Join with the Index of Array I am using

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want my code to concat a array with its index, using Join

x=['G','r','e','e','t']
x.join(`${index}`)
then x should be G0r1e2e3t4

can I achieve this using join?

Comment: `join` takes a constant string.

Comment: Yeah Thanks , i just want clarity that if it can use some dynamic values or not.

Comment: btw, your last item does not get a delimiter at the end with `join`.

Comment: An index is generally found as an argument in a callback (see `forEach`, `map`, `reduce` etc.) [`join` doesn't have a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - just an optional operator parameter - so using its "index" is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
['G','r','e','e','t'].map((e, i) => e + i).join('')
```

Comment: It seems fine , but I was thinking if that was possible so i could use Index itself inside Join.

Comment: `join()` takes the desired delimiter as its argument, which would change between each set of characters. You could do it, but it would be making it much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Ok can you show, any example?

Comment: Why do you *need* the index in the join?  This is a perfectly reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```js
const arr = ['G','r','e','e','t'];
const result = arr.reduce(
  (accumulator, current, index) => accumulator + current + index,
  []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(
  ['G','r','e','e','t'].reduce((a,c,i)=>a+c+i,'')
)
```